# Get Transform of selected Locator in Maya using CMDS

Tags: python, maya

Using Maya's cmds (python) how can i check if the user has a Locator selected, and then get that locators Transform?

I tried using this, but im not to familiar with maya python...

```
nodes = cmds.filterExpand(sm=22) # check if user has a locator selected
if not len(nodes) == 1:
     return
# not sure if this is the proper method to use, can i pass in my nodes from the method above like i have written?
tm = cmds.ls(nodes[0], sl=True, transforms=True)
# ... from here i can work on TM assuming it's the transform ex. Locator1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension to collect all selected transforms that have locator shapes like so:

```
[obj for obj in cmds.ls(sl=True) if cmds.listRelatives(obj, shapes=True, type="locator")]
```

To break it down, `cmds.ls(sl=True)` will return a list of all selected objects. Then to filter that we can use `cmds.listRelatives` to check if the transform has any shapes as locators, and if so, collect it.